# Where can I download older version AWS-Mobile-SDK

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I need the `AWS SNS` 2.5.5 SDK for iOS, but now I can only download the 2.5.9 version at the official page https://aws.amazon.com/tw/mobile/sdk/

I have read the release notes but there is no link for different version SDKs.

So I try to build it by the source code in Github https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios, but the Xcode settings may not be the same with the CI of AWS using.

Does anyone know how to download an older version mobile SDK for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to download it using : http://sdk-for-ios.amazonwebservices.com/aws-ios-sdk-2.5.5.zip

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!